# Multiple &nbsp; being automatically inserted into visual studio editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Am facing a strange problem with Visual Studio HTML editor. While we are formatting the code or saving the code or sometimes without any reason multiple `$nbsp;` being inserted to the HTML. This is becoming a headache for me since its inserting to most of the areas. So what I've to do is to search for every  `$nbsp;` and replacing it with blank. Anyone know the reason behind this strange phenomena of visual studio or anyone knows a solution for this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem in vs2015 as well.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this happens when you run your project while the Designer is still open.

There are discussions about it [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1253201.aspx?Designer%20adding%20many%20non%20breaking%20spaces) and [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1485800.aspx?How%20to%20create%20a%20flipcart%20like%20panel%20for%20showing%20products%20in%20gridview).

Answer (score 0):

Friends there is a simple solution for this...
Remove all spaces and carriage returns with in the control. Problem will be solved

for eg: if your control is like

```
<Select>
 <Option>1</Option>
 <Option>2</Option>
</Select>
```

Solution is to make the mark up as following
12

Let me know whether you are still facing this issue